# Ratio of MbO2/Mb in a satured solution of dissolved oxygen from dry air

Tags: thermodynamics

> What is the ratio of $\ce{MbO2/Mb}$ if the solution is saturated with air?
>
> **Details of the question**:
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \ce{Mb + O2 (aq) &-> MbO2}\\
> \Delta G' &= -30.3~\mathrm{kJ/mol}\\
> T &= 298~\mathrm{K}\\
> \ce{pH} &= 7\\
> \text{Henry's Constant for }\ce{O2}  &= 42 \cdot 10^3~\mathrm{bar}\\
> \text{Content of }\ce{O2}\text{ in dry air} &= 21\%\\
> \end{align}
> $$

**Attempt at Solution**:

So, basically this is a two part question, as I see it. First I need to figure out the concentration of dissolved $\ce{O2}$ using Henry's Law. Then I can simply plug this value into the $$\Delta G' = -RT\ln K$$ equation where $$K = \frac{\ce{[MbO2]}}{\ce{[O2][Mb]}}.$$

Therefore:
$$
\begin{align}
P &= K\cdot m\\
0.21~\mathrm{bar} &= (42 \cdot 10^3)\cdot m\\
m &= 5 \cdot 10^{-6} \pu{mol/kg}\\
-30.300~\mathrm{J/mol} &= -8.314 \cdot 298 \cdot \ln\left(\frac{\ce{[MbO2]}}{[5\cdot10^{-6}]\ce{[Mb]}}\right)
\end{align}
$$
After dividing and raising both sides to $e^x$ (to get rid of $\ln$) I get $$\frac{\ce{MbO2}}{\ce{Mb}} = 1.02.$$

However the answer sheet says it is $21.6$. I cannot figure out why this is so.

Comment: I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). Please do not use markup in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details. || For the ones unfamiliar (like me) with this kind of chemistry, it would be nice, if you could introduce your variables. What is $m$ or $P$? As a general remark: You should include units in every step.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I didn't know how to use the markup. Also units have been included where necessary (except for m which I have now included). I will, however, try to be more clear in the future

Comment: You are very welcome. As for the units, you should include them always and everywhere, they are usually the first hint that something went wrong, when they don't cancel correctly.

Comment: I don't have time to answer properly, but I am inclined to think that the mistake is in the Henry's Law calculation.  Usually when the constant is given as a pressure, the formula calculates a mole fraction rather than a molality.  The answer you were given works back to a *molarity* of 1.1x10^-4M for oxygen, and water is 55 mol/L, so that works out nicely.  @Martin It's the units that point me in that direction.

Comment: While I admit that there is an error in using molality instead of mole fractions, even after using mole fractions I am getting an answer of **2.78 x 10^-4 Mol/L** for the O2 concentration